# A and its transpose have the same minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

Help, I need to prove the next

Prove that A and A^t have the same minimal polynomial

I have proved that they have the same characteristic polynomial, therefore its minimal polinomial divides the characteristic poynomial, but, is that enough to prove it?

Comment: It is not necessarily true that two matrices with the same characteristic polynomial have the same minimal polynomial, so what you have proven is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Go back to the definition of the minimal polynomial noting that for every polynomial $p$, we have $p(A^T) = p(A)^T$.